# Author with email in tikzposter with affiliation index in name

Tags: tikzposter, author, authblk, email

I am customizing a theme using as base tikzposter. My authors here have each one some shared affiliations and the emails will not look good with the affiliation since would be confusing the relation between affiliation markers and the email (an email might be related to two authors and that is not desired). If I put the email after name with a linebreak the affiliation symbol will be in the email and not in the name. My current MWE is below. ¿How can I still have emails in authors but marker affiliation right after the name?

```
\documentclass[a0paper, landscape]{tikzposter}

\usepackage{authblk}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\TP@maketitle{%
    \hspace{3em}
    \begin{minipage}{0.7\linewidth}
         %\centering
         \color{titlefgcolor}
         {\bfseries \Huge \sc \@title \par}
         \vspace*{1em}
         {\LARGE \@author \par}
         \vspace*{1em}
         {\LARGE \@institute}
    \end{minipage}%
    \hfill
}

\makeatother

\makeatletter
\def\maketitle{\AB@maketitle}
\renewcommand\AB@affilsepx{\quad\protect\Affilfont} % put affiliations 
into one line
\makeatother
\renewcommand\Affilfont{\Large}

\usetheme{Wave}


\title{ \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
Super long long long long long long long long long long long long long 
long long title
\end{minipage}}

\author[1]{Homer Simpson \\ marge@thesimpsons.com}
\author[1,2]{Marge Simpson}
\author[3]{Lisa Simpson}
\author[4]{Bart Simpson}

\affil[1]{\normalsize University of North}
\affil[2]{\normalsize Scientific Center of the north}
\affil[3]{\normalsize The University of Love}
\affil[4]{\normalsize University of Life}



\begin{document}
\maketitle
\block{hi}{example}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As I mentioned in chat, it's not entirely clear to me exactly what kind of layout you want. Can you try to clarify, or make a visual representation of what you want?